# how to rename column name and cast type when do aggregation in pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe, and I wish to get the mean and std for all columns, and rename the columns name and type, what is the easiest way to implement this, currently below is my code:

```
    test_mean=test.groupby('id').agg({'col1': 'mean',
                                      'col2': 'mean',
                                      'col3':'mean'
                                     })
    test_std=test.groupby('id').agg({'col1': 'std',
                                     'col2': 'std',
                                     'col3':'std'
                                     })
  ##rename one columns by one columns 
  ## type cast decimal to float
```

May I know how to improve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Col experssioons:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

expr1 = F.std(F.col('col1').cast('integer').alias('col1'))
expr2 = F.std(F.col('col2').cast('integer').alias('col2'))
test \
    .groupBy(id) \
    .agg(
         expr1, 
         expr2

)
```